# Mysql rotates the relay logs at 100mb when `max_relay_log_size = 1G`

Tags: mysql, replication

Why mysql rotates the relay logs at 100mb when `max_relay_log_size = 1G` ?

Is mysql should rotate the log file only if the size to exceed the value of `max_relay_log_size` variable?

```
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        255 Jun 30 19:14 mysqld-relay-bin.000011
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  104858982 Jun 30 19:18 mysqld-relay-bin.000012
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        255 Jun 30 19:18 mysqld-relay-bin.000013
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql   22305643 Jun 30 19:20 mysqld-relay-bin.000014
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        208 Jun 30 19:20 mysqld-relay-bin.000015
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql   84483918 Jun 30 19:23 mysqld-relay-bin.000016
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        255 Jun 30 19:23 mysqld-relay-bin.000017
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  104981742 Jun 30 19:26 mysqld-relay-bin.000018
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        255 Jun 30 19:26 mysqld-relay-bin.000019
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  104862635 Jun 30 19:30 mysqld-relay-bin.000020
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        255 Jun 30 19:30 mysqld-relay-bin.000021
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  104862297 Jun 30 19:35 mysqld-relay-bin.000022
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        255 Jun 30 19:35 mysqld-relay-bin.000023
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  105150321 Jun 30 19:38 mysqld-relay-bin.000024
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        255 Jun 30 19:38 mysqld-relay-bin.000025
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  104861615 Jun 30 19:43 mysqld-relay-bin.000026
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        255 Jun 30 19:43 mysqld-relay-bin.000027
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql    2467221 Jun 30 19:43 mysqld-relay-bin.000028
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql      87680 Jun 30 19:43 mysqld-relay-log.index
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql         84 Jun 30 19:43 relay-log.info



binlog_format = ROW
log-bin = /data/binlogs/mysql-bin
log-bin-index = /data/binlogs/mysql-bin.index
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
max_binlog_size = 2G
relay-log-info-file = /data/binlogs/relay-log.info
relay-log-index = /data/binlogs/mysqld-relay-log.index
relay-log = /data/mysql/mysqld-relay-bin
max_relay_log_size = 1G
relay_log_space_limit = 0
expire_logs_days=14
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1



Variable_name              Value                                 
-------------------------  --------------------------------------
max_relay_log_size         1073741824                            
relay_log                  /data/binlogs/mysqld-relay-bin        
relay_log_basename         /data/binlogs/mysqld-relay-bin        
relay_log_index            /data/binlogs/mysqld-relay-log.index  
relay_log_info_file        /data/binlogs/relay-log.info          
relay_log_info_repository  FILE                                  
relay_log_purge            ON                                    
relay_log_recovery         OFF                                   
relay_log_space_limit      0                                     
sync_relay_log             10000                                 
sync_relay_log_info        10000
```

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

**update**

Now there are almost no relay logs, is it because the relay logs are purged automatically when the slave has finished applying the data from them, meaning `second behind master = 0` ?

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql       4096 Jul  1 20:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 mysql mysql         98 Feb 19 14:57 ../
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        177 Jul  1 13:41 mysql-bin.000001
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1073979508 Jul  1 14:14 mysql-bin.000002
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1122063688 Jul  1 14:36 mysql-bin.000003
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1073760829 Jul  1 15:21 mysql-bin.000004
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1073747080 Jul  1 16:11 mysql-bin.000005
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1076996640 Jul  1 17:02 mysql-bin.000006
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1073742632 Jul  1 17:51 mysql-bin.000007
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1073742448 Jul  1 18:42 mysql-bin.000008
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1073951285 Jul  1 19:29 mysql-bin.000009
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 1073741986 Jul  1 20:17 mysql-bin.000010
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  911962461 Jul  1 20:59 mysql-bin.000011
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        341 Jul  1 20:17 mysql-bin.index
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql        255 Jul  1 20:56 mysqld-relay-bin.000754
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql   45170435 Jul  1 20:59 mysqld-relay-bin.000755
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql         76 Jul  1 20:56 mysqld-relay-log.index
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql         86 Jul  1 20:59 relay-log.info
```

**update**

I see the following warning in mysql.log file `option 'max_binlog_size': unsigned value 2147483648 adjusted to 1073741824`.

Comment: Have you tried writing it as `max_relay_log_size = 1073741824` and see if it makes a difference? Is there any possibility this setting is *dynamically changed*? It is actually [dynamic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_relay_log_size), so it can be changed via SQL.

Comment: @joanolo, I am using `max_relay_log_size = 1G`, but I wrote an update to my question, did you see ?

Comment: That's a huge amount of data being shipped through -- please verify that `server-id` is different on each machine.

Comment: I wonder what caused the "255" byte files.  Any change someone is doing a `FLUSH`?

Comment: How come the  binlogs are 1GB if `max_binlog_size = 2G`?

Comment: @RickJames, server-ids are different between the machines.

Comment: @RickJames, mysqld-relay-bin `255` byte, is it because the relay logs are purged automatically when the slave has finished applying the data from them, meaning second behind master = 0 ?

Comment: @RickJames, Now I see this `[Warning] option 'max_binlog_size': unsigned value 2147483648 adjusted to 1073741824`, do you have any idea why ? thanks

Comment: I guess this is a limitation based on old 32-bit days.  As soon the file is bigger than the max, it will stop adding.  This means it will go a little past 1G.  If it went past 2G there would be issue with signed/unsigned in a 32-bit compiler.  1G is plenty for a binlog; the new default seems to be 100M, which is also fine.

Comment: Alas, I guess I can't answer the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a limitation based on old 32-bit days. As soon the file is bigger than the max, it will stop adding. This means it will go a little past 1G. If it went past 2G there would be issue with signed/unsigned in a 32-bit compiler. 1G is plenty for a binlog; the new default seems to be 100M, which is also fine.

As for the `max_relay_log_size = 1G` became a 100M limit, I don't know.  But, again, it should not matter.  The additional 255-byte files make me wonder if your code is doing some sort of `FLUSH LOGS` every so often.